# How does the compiler knows the function which is imported by dll?

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-construction

I have a question about header files in c++.
The functions which were in ntdll.dll can not be called normally.
(We can call function when we include it's header file , but nt API's 
always be called by GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "FuncName").

So i searched about nt functions , and some people said that there is no header files about ntdll.dll in officialy, So i must use GetProcAddress to call them.

What is a header files? 
How does compiler can knows the dll function which is linked to header file?
(For EX, If we use MessageBox() , then the compiler knows it is in kernel32.dll )
Maybe I guess..there is the dll import context(syntax) in the header files,
For example like... windows.h has the import "kernel32.dll" context, so complier
can knows that. Is it true?

Comment: The thing is - compiler doesn't know that. The whole nature of .dlls are, that they are **dynamically** linked libraries. The address, of a procedure you call is resolved at runtime.

Comment: You either need a declaration (usually in an API header) and a lib file or you need to use `GetProcAddress` and "know" what you need from documentation. The lib file is what knows what DLL the function is located in, not the header.

Comment: thanks a lot @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: @crashmstr thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `.lib` files too. it contains function addresses. dll `.h` files that doesn't need `.lib` can only attempt to find these addresses selfstate (smth like you re talkin about)